# Network gateway with OpenVPN and HAProxy on one server --> routing problems

Tags: linux, debian, networking, iptables, routing

I am setting up a gateway for my network that includes a reverse proxy (HAProxy) and a openvpn server on the same machine.

I want to use the openvpn to connect to a vpn provider so that all the traffic from my network is encrypted.

The problem now is that as soon as I open up the connection to the vpn provider it pushes new routes to my routing table. Those routes are conflicting with my HAProxy that cannot access my internal servers.

Routing table without connecting to the vpn provider:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    203    0        0 eth1
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     203    0        0 eth1
```

Routing table after connecting to the vpn provider:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.8.3.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun1
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    203    0        0 eth1
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
10.8.3.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun1
123.243.152.126 192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
128.0.0.0       10.8.3.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun1
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     203    0        0 eth1
```

I followed following guide to setup the routing and nat rules: https://gist.github.com/superjamie/ac55b6d2c080582a3e64

I want to route all trafic that is reaching eth1 through tun1 which is the connection to the vpn provider.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun1 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tun1 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o tun1 -j ACCEPT
```

All the requests on eth0 are not supposed to go through that tunnel. Instead they are meant to go either to my internal servers or respond to request from a client from outside the network.

Comment: contrary to (misleading) information often found on net, iptables rarely does routing. It *allows* routed packets. When it does NAT in *POSTROUTING* it doesn't route, it did it *after* routing was done. To do routing, routing commands must be used. For this case it's policy routing, using routing rules to enable multiple tables, thus enabling correct use of multiple default routes (correct use as in  one per table)

Comment: For starters, there is already something wrong with routing without activating the VPN,  there should not be there  two default gateways. Furthermore, some VPNs are also configured as full tunnel VPNs, and by design they interfere with the normal routing. This seems more a networking/routing/security question *than* a Linux question.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro it's a common OpenVPN's trick: it's creating two half-default routes to take precedence over the actual default route. those routes are /1, not /0.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro should I post my question in a different section?

Comment: Well I'm attempting to provide a linux solution, so afaik that stays on topic here. Can't promise I give it soon or at all though.

Comment: @A.B Thank you. Lets hope for the best :)

Comment: I would leave it here. But I still think part o the question seems to be a lack of understanding how routing/VPN works. I see priorities there for gateways, though the question does not mention why they are there.

Comment: Hum anyway @RuiFRibeiro you were right, in addition to the two half default routes, there *are* two default routes too. One too much. So indeed something is wrong even before. Sorry to have not seen it correctly at start

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I am definitely no expert in that field and that is why I came here to ask for help. The two default gateways are there by default. Maybe I should delete one of the default gateways?

Comment: @DJMcMuffin : unless hidden stuff is around (hidden in ip rule and more tables) the routes through eth1 are not supposed to work. Can you explain in what case you're using eth1? Can you *confirm* it does work  when you're using eth1, and how you're using it then?

Comment: @A.B currently all the traffic that is going to my internal servers are going through eth1 and to the HAProxy. So I can say with certainty that it goes at least to the right interface but I cannot say if it leaves the server on eth1. Is there a way to find out?

Comment: No problem at all, was just overthinking about the origin of the question. Enjoy our community.

Comment: @A.B That /1 trick seems also to be used by my CheckPoint client. As someone made some mistake filtering internal routes, I just tell the kernel to drop all the tun routes after connecting to the VPN and build a much more saner and smaller routing table.

Comment: @DJMcMuffin : https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.5/configuration.html#4.2-source HA proxy binds to the interface, thus bypassing some default routing

Comment: so there are 3 concurrent thing to make work together: a non standard haproxy feature (says works only on Linux and to use with care), a VPN software, and additional routing rules. I'm not confident not breaking something heh.

Comment: @A.B I am willing to experiment or to alternatives :)

Comment: Well I'm sorry I give up. Again just noticed *now* there is `tun0` *and* `tun1`. There is no way I can spit something correct. Too many things put together. Sorry.

Comment: @A.B Thank you for taking the time though. I figured that the project is a little too much